# Pandas Column Split (Array)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Below is my data in SQL Server

[image]

After reading data in python it become like this

[image]

I use the below code to split the value to multiple columns

```
# 1. To split single array column to multiple column based on '\t'
df[['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5','v6','v7','v8','v9','v10','v11','v12','v13','v14','v15',\
       'v16','v17','v18','v19','v20','v21','v22','v23','v24','v25','v26','v27','v28',\
'v29','v30','v31','v32','v33','v34','v35','v36','v37','v38','v39','v40','v41']] = df['_VALUE'].str.split(pat="\t", expand=True)

# 2. To remove the '\r\n' from the last column
df['v41'] = df['v41'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True)
```

But in some data sets the array value is more Eg. 100 columns, the above code is so big. I have to write from V1 to V100. Is there any simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the hardcoded array from your code with one that generates the array for you using a method like this:

```
df[[f'v{x}' for x in range(100)]] = df['_VALUE'].str.split(pat="\t", expand=True)
```

Comment: 1) we can. First of all, I propose to find the maximum number of columns:
`max(list([x.count('\t")+1 for x in df['_VALUE']]))`
This string can be entered instead of 100.
2. Here is a challenge just another. Since there will be a different last column for each row, then you will have to change the past solution slightly.
Create a column with the number of columns in the line:
`df['columns_num'] = list([x.count('\t")+1 for x in df['_VALUE']]))`
And then already replace the desired column
`df.iloc[i, x].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True)`

Comment: max(list([x.count('\t")+1 for x in df['_VALUE']])) - code keeps running so long. i think it searches all the rows in df of column _VALUE

Comment: Are there so many lines? You can then try through apply, but I don't remember exactly the syntax. Try to look at an example of a couple of lines, what generally produces  `list([x.count('\t")+1 for x in df['_VALUE']]`

Comment: HM. Now I checked it on my data. It works well for me

Comment: yes, the data frame has many rows. it's recorded in milliseconds so

Comment: Then you have to wait